# Get the index of view from which a button was clicked in a NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have a `NSCollectionView` and I am adding my custom view which acts as `NSCollectionViewItem` for that collection view. In my collectionViewItem, I have a `NSButton` along with various other elements. I have a method `onButtonClick` which is connected to that button. Now, suppose I add 5 items of my collectonViewItem on to the collectionView. 
How can I get the index of the view from where the button was clicked?

Inside `onButtonClick`, I tried following code but it always returns 0 regardless of which button I click:

```
id collectionViewItem = [sender superView];
NSInteger index = [[colloectionView subviews]  indexOfObject:collectionViewItem];
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant return index by clicking a control (which having its own functon).i think you have to see http://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/nscollectionview-tutorial-for-dummies-xcode-3-1-3/.
before that check collectionview selection as selectable in attributes inspector.(and also try by disable the button)