# Get index of current selected object in NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nscollectionview

I want to have the index of the current selected Dictionary of an NSCollectionView.

I have this code but it always returns "0".

```
- (IBAction)selectItem:(id)sender {
    NSInteger index = [[CollectionView subviews]  indexOfObject:self.representedObject];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)index);
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A NScollectionView is a panel that displays all items in a collection.  What do you expect "IndexOf" to represent?  If you expect the current selection, it looks like there is a "selection" item that you can use to get the currently selected item.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814028/get-the-index-of-view-from-which-a-button-was-clicked-in-a-nscollectionview?rq=1

Comment: @BenPen okey, thats what i mean. So i am going to try that link tommorow